# Determining a line such that it crosses other line with some constraints

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm given two equations:
$y=ax+b$ and $y=(\tan\alpha)x + d$
For simplicity I made a substitution $c = \tan\alpha$

I do know the values of $a$ and $b$, and that the first line goes through point $\vec{p_1}$ and second one through $\vec{p_2}$, both of which are known. Also, let's call the point where those two lines intersect $\vec{I}$

Now, with all that data I need to find $c$ and $d$ such that $\frac{|\vec{p_1}-\vec{I}|}{|\vec{p_2}-\vec{I}|}=f$ for given $f$ or determine that those two don't exist.

I tried to solve this by 'brute force' but algebra I had to deal with was so terrifying that I simply didn't manage to find any solution.

//edit: Maybe this will clear out the problem. I'm not a good graphics designer tho.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fairly straightforward if you convert the equation of the line through $\mathbf p_1$ to the parametric form $\mathbf p_1+\lambda\mathbf v$, where $\mathbf v={1\over\sqrt{1+a^2}}(1,a)$, the unit direction vector of the line. The absolute value of the parameter $\lambda$ is the distance along this line from $\mathbf p_1$, which means that the intersection point must satisfy $$\lambda=f\|\mathbf p_1+\lambda\mathbf v-\lambda\mathbf p_2\|.$$ Squaring both sides, we get $$\begin{align} \lambda^2 &= f^2\|\mathbf p_1+\lambda\mathbf v-\mathbf p_2\|^2 \\ &=f^2\|\mathbf p_1-\mathbf p_2\|^2 +2f^2\lambda\mathbf v\cdot(\mathbf p_1-\mathbf p_2)+f^2\lambda^2, \end{align}$$ a quadratic equation in $\lambda$ with solution $$\lambda = {f^2\over f^2-1}\mathbf v\cdot(\mathbf p_2-\mathbf p_1)\pm\sqrt{\left({f^2\over f^2-1}\mathbf v\cdot(\mathbf p_2-\mathbf p_1)\right)^2-{f^2\over f^2-1}\|\mathbf p_2-\mathbf p_1\|^2}$$ for $f^2\ne1$, and $$\lambda=f{\|\mathbf p_2-\mathbf p_1\|^2\over2\mathbf v\cdot(\mathbf p_2-\mathbf p_1)}$$ for $f^2=1$. For the latter case, there is no solution when $\mathbf v\cdot(\mathbf p_2-\mathbf p_1)=0$. (These equations can also be derived by applying the Law of Cosines to $\triangle{P_1P_2I}$.) I assume that you know how to find the equations of the lines through $\mathbf p_2$ and these points, but be careful: a solution line might be vertical, in which case it can’t be represented by an equation of the form $y=cx+d$.

Comment: Thanks for reply! I don't u derstand third step, how did you get (p1-p2) there? Isn't that a vector? That would imply that lambda also is a vector while it should be a scalar, right?

Comment: @KamilKoczurek It comes from expanding $\|\mathbf p_1+\lambda\mathbf v-\mathbf p_2\|^2$ as $(\mathbf p_1-\mathbf p_2+\lambda\mathbf v)\cdot(\mathbf p_1-\mathbf p_2+\lambda\mathbf v)$. (Note that I left off the exponent in the preceding line. Fixed now.) After expanding, vectors appear only as terms of dot products, so the entire expression is a scalar.

Comment: Thanks, now all of it makes sense to me. :)